# How to get csv file from current session in php?

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, pdo

The logic is "to get info from form that current user filled, insert into db and give it him(to user) back in .csv format file". But in csv file the data is repeated twice as shown in screenshot attached in the bottom of this question. If you have faced with such situation could you help me please?

Whole index.php:

```
  <?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['first_name'];

  try {
       $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'someuser', '123456');
       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      print $e->getMessage();
  }

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
      if(validate()) {
          process();
      }
  } else {
      show();
  }

  function validate() {
      $phoneLength = strlen($_POST['phone']);
      if($phoneLength==11) {
              return true;
      } else {
          print "Phone number must contain more than $phoneLength characters.";
      }
  }

  function process(){
      try{
          // Insert into db
          $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO personalInfo (first_name, last_name, email, phone) 
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
          $stmt->execute(array($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], 
                        $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone']));
    
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
          print $e->getMessage();
      }

      // Get file
      header('Content-type: text/csv');
      header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename: info.csv');

      $fh = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
      $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM personalInfo WHERE first_name = '{$_SESSION['user_fname']}' ");
      while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
          fputcsv($fh, $row);
      }
  }

  function show(){
      print<<<_HTML_
      <form method='POST' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>
          <input name='first_name' type='text' placeholder='Your first name' required><br>
          <input name='last_name' type='text' placeholder='Your last name' required><br>
          <input name='email' type='email' placeholder='Your e-mail' required><br>
          <input name='phone' type='number' placeholder='Your phone number' required><br>
         <input type='submit' value='GET'>
     </form>
     _HTML_;
  }
```

Problem zone:

```
      // Get file
      header('Content-type: text/csv');
      header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename: info.csv');

      $fh = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
      $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM personalInfo WHERE first_name = '{$_SESSION['user_fname']}' ");
      while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
          fputcsv($fh, $row);
      }
```

It shows:
[Double writing each column data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfBcR.png)
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation. The [manual for the PDO fetch function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) says it accepts an optional argument called "mode", and this is what it says about that option:

> mode: Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller ... defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH

and

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

So you're getting the same data twice because PDO returns it twice. `$row` will contain an array of the same data - once in associative (named) fields, and once in numbered fields. And then `fputcsv` just processes the whole array without discrimination.

For your purpose, a basic numbered array would be sufficient, so you can just tell PDO to return only that:

```
$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```